# Strip attribute name from result set?

Tags: html, xmllint

I have a HTML document that looks (when oversimplified) like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="...">...</a>
    <a href="...">...</a>
    <a href="...">...</a>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

What I'd like to do would be to extract the URLs in line-delimited output. Enter xmllint:

```
$ xmllint --html --xpath //a/@href
href="..." href="..." href="..."
```

It's getting the attribute, the whole attribute including the name, and it's outputting them space-delimited. How can I just get a list of lines with the values of the `href` attribute? I want output like this:

```
...
...
...
```

where `...` is the URL found in the `href` attribute of each `a` element.

How can I format this output properly?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965071/get-xmllint-to-output-xpath-results-n-separated-for-attribute-selector) help?

Comment: don't do that thing in that link!

Answer (score 1):

Given `file.html`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="url1">link text 1</a>
    <a href="url2">link text 2</a>
    <a href="url3">link text 3</a>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

We can use Unix pipes to send existing `xmllint`'s output, to `sed` and see this result:

```
$ xmllint --html --xpath //a/@href input.html | sed 's/ href="\([^"]*\)"/\1\n/g'
url1
url2
url3
```

### Explanation

With `xmllint` alone, we only get:

```
$ xmllint --html --xpath //a/@href input.html
 href="url1" href="url2" href="url3"%
```

- the trailing `%` indicates there is no trailing newline

One of the benefits of Unix-like systems is we can benefit from [Doug McIlroy's pipes](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch01s06.html) feature, so we don't have to have one program try to do everything, we are in fact encouraged to combine programs to suit our needs.

So, finding `xmllint`'s output unsatisfactory, we pipe to combine it with our `sed` command, which:

- searches for `href="URL"` units
- using `\(` `\)` grouping to surround the URL part
- and replacing it with `\1\n` so it references the group we defined around the URL, while also adding a new line after that matched `\1`

In this way we combine `xmllint` and `sed` to obtain the desired line-delimited output, one URL per line.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using sed:

`sed -n 's/.*href="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p'`

Comment: that gets only one per line - and i mean input lines not output lines. and so you lose `<a href="http...."> </a> <a href="http....">` the first. it also gets `<div text_attribute="bla...href="... all of this ... "`

Comment: You are right. I used the sample from above which has each `href` on separate lines. @mikeserv

Comment: you can do it - you just need to be more conservative. the `.*` is usually an issue for these kinds of things.

Comment: [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/234830/52934) might help as an example. and there's [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251588/52934).

Comment: no problem. let me know if you work it out so i can upvote a worthy edit.